# Logging a long response time as a failure in JMeter

Tags: web-services, jmeter

I am using JMeter and the HTTP Request sampler to load test an web API

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure JMeter so it logs a request as a failure if it takes longer than a certain threshold (e.g. 1000 ms)

Right now if only logs an error if the response is a 500 or something.

Comment: I think that you have to use Duration Assertion http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest option would be adding a [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)

However if it is not flexible enough you can always go deeper and use Beanshell. Following updated code sample from previous response by *Nithin CV poyyil* will mark request as failed if duration exceeds some reasonable value:

```
long expectedDuration = 1000L;
long actualDuration = prev.getTime();

if (actualDuration > expectedDuration) {
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
    prev.setResponseMessage("Request took longer than " + expectedDuration);
}
```

See [How to use BeanShell guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for reference and small cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is you need to add **Beanshell Postprocessor** to request sampler for logging certain requests within particular response time threshold,

```
long duration = prev.getTime();

if(duration>1000){
    log.error("Time Out..... !!!!");
}
```

Hope this may help you.